# problem with free download manager

Tags: download-manager

I have installed fdm on my computer in order to continue downloads after a shutdown. But there is one problem. It slows down my browsing even if I have already paused the downloads(downloading at bytes per second). And it is already on light mode(wherein it says that it will consume less bandwidth)
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what is it doing with your connection when you've paused your downloads?

Sorry, but I tend to view download managers with suspicion, especially ones which allow people to "...operate the program remotely, via the internet".

Try running [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) from (Microsoft's [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) site) and study what connections FDM makes.
You could also use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to monitor what it sends and receives.

Comment: thanks for the advice, now I'll be more careful when using dmanagers

Comment: But FDM is awesome!

Comment: If it's awesome, then it won't be abusing the connection and slowing things down. And checking with TCPView and WireShark will prove that.

Answer (score 0):

No! that's not suspicious!
Download managers cannot stop using internet when they are limited or paused (The way that FDM does. Pausing at 1bytes/sec to "resume" Unresummable downloads).
So you have one choice! Using a bandwidth limiter software and limit it to for example 2 KBytes/sec when you "pause" it.
My choice is NetBalancer but others are helpful too.